# Avoiding the display of the null values while using simple_slider

Tags: flutter, dart

Am displaying multiple url images using the simple_slider package, my list comprises of 10 variables that may be null or not, how can i exclude displaying the null values in the slider.

```
_buildProductImagesWidgets(){
   final _imageUrls = [pic1 ?? '',pic2 ?? '',pic3 ?? '',pic4 ?? '',pic5 ??'',pic6 ?? '',pic7 ?? '',pic8 ?? '',pic9 ?? '',pic10 ?? ''];
   return Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
     child: Container(
       height: 350.0,
       child: Center(
         child: ImageSliderWidget(
           imageUrls: _imageUrls,
           imageBorderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
         ),
       ),
     ),
   );}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 final _imageUrls = [pic1 ?? '',pic2 ?? '',pic3 ?? '',pic4 ?? '',pic5 ??'',pic6 ?? '',pic7 ?? '',pic8 ?? '',pic9 ?? '',pic10 ?? ''];
```

with

```
final _imageUrls = [pic1,pic2,pic3,pic4,pic5,pic6,pic7,pic8,pic9,pic10].where((x) => x!=null).toList();
```